# How to play Kaltura media playlist on tv/web/mobile devices

Tags: video, video-streaming, television, kaltura

Any one please tell me
How to play Kaltura media playlist to TV(using devices like mediaDROID & mediaBOX) 
on web as well as on mobile devices.

Please tell if there is any open source plugin available for same.

Answer (score 0):

I believe those devices can take an MRSS feed for input, so you can "syndicate" your Kaltura videos (or a subset of them on a specific playlist) to them.

Here's the info, from Kaltura: http://cdnknowledge.kaltura.com//sites/default/files/Kaltura%20Content%20Syndication.pdf

To syndicate just some videos, create a custom data field called "mrss" with two options, yes or no. Edit each video you want to have syndicated and change the 'mrss' option to yes. Finally, then create a custom playlist which contains only items where the custom data field 'mrss' = 'yes'. And then when you create your MRSS feed (following the docs linked above), you can tell it to publish only that playlist.